# (Proof Correction): Suppose $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ which is cont. diff. and $|f'(x)| \leq 1/2$, then it has unique fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis

My proof: (assume existence is proved) Suppose their exist two fixed points $y$ and $z$, then $\mid f(y)-f(z) \mid = \mid y-z \mid .\mid f'(x) \mid$ for some $y \leq x \leq z$ by mean value property. Since $y, z$ are fixed points, we have  $\mid y- z \mid = \mid y-z \mid .\mid f'(x) \mid$ or $\mid f'(x) \mid = 1$ which is a contradiction. Hence the result.
What I don't understand is where did I made use of the assumption that $f$ is continuosly differenciable.

Comment: You did not prove that it has a fixed point. You only proved that it does not have more than one.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes, but for existence,we need only continuoity; apparently, for uniqueness, we need only differentiability with the given bound (or even just Lipschitz with a constant $<1$). I do not see either why *continuous* differentiability should be needed

Comment: The MVT argument gives that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $\tfrac{1}{2}<1$. The uniqueness and existence of a fixed point follows from Banach's contraction principle.

Comment: @uniquesolution ya my bad, actually I proved the existence in a previous question of my assignment and forgot to say so  in question.

Comment: @max_zorn I am not sure if I am allowed to appeal to such advance concepts/theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a fixed point follows from just continuity and examining 
$$
g(x)=f(x)-x
$$
Note that $g(0)\geq 0$ and $g(1)\leq 0$. If either one is actually $0$, we have our fixed point. If neither are, we may conclude the function has a zero on the interval by the intermediate value theorem.

Your proof looks perfectly fine to me and it is ok to relax the restriction to just differentiable on $[0,1]$ with your bound on the derivative.

Comment: @gbert: you are right I deleted

Comment: no problem, it happens